# Apple-pay with Stripe not recognized in Dashboard

Tags: javascript, ios, stripe-payments, applepay

I seem to have gotten backend index.js file working with an apple-pay payment request on the back-end. However the results do not show up in my Stripe dashboard. Spinning my wheels and cannot figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the code I am using on the back-end. When I press the pay button in Apple-Pay in the App, my terminal window shows "Payment requested" and "Success" messages.

I would then expect the USD amount to process in my stripe dashboard but I am gettin $0.00 and no activity. Any help would be wonderful!

```js
// Add packages we need
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var stripe = require('stripe')('YOUR-SECRET-KEY')

// Create an express app
const app = express()

// Use body parser so we can parse the body of requests
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Just a sanity check endpoint we can hit in the browser
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('This is the backend server for Metatoll Application!')
})

app.post('/pay', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Payment requested')

  var token = req.body.stripeToken
  var amount = req.body.amount
  var description = req.body.description

  stripe.charges.create({ 
  amount: amount,
  currency: "usd",
  description: description,
  source: token,
  }, function(err, charge) {
    if (err !== null) {
      console.log('error capturing')
      console.log(err)
      res.status(400).send('error')
    } else {
      console.log('success')
      res.status(200).send('success')
    }
  });
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Metatoll listening on port 3000')
})
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing amount with a value? Like 100 for $1 (think it needs to be in cents). amount: 100 inside the create method. Also I assume you changed the API key to `YOUR-SECRET-KEY` for this post right?

Comment: I did. Same issue persists. I also did change my secret key to the test key given to me in the stripe dashboard.

Comment: Is it an `int`? Checking the docs needs to be `A positive integer`. In the stripe dashboard on the charge thats showing $0.00, you should check the request logs that stripe are receiving.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking in live mode data, but this happens in test mode, or vice versa? Make sure to toggle to test mode in your dashboard : https://i.imgur.com/f9VLesb.png Otherwise, if you log `charge.id` from that code and write to Stripe's support, they might be able to help track it down